# apache rewrite all URLs to HTTPS except for one

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

I have a website that I'm directing all non SSL traffic to use the https protocol.

I've used

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This works great, but I need the url

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/update-db.php
```

to not follow this rule.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I need to redirect my downloads for IE8 because it has a bug when using SSL. Just take out the **RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.*)MSIE\ 8.(.*)$ [NC]** and replace **viewpdf** with your php file in your case.

```
RewriteEngine On
#Fix for IE8 SSL Bug downloading PDF
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.*)MSIE\ 8\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(viewpdf.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(viewpdf.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(viewpdf.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply just:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update-db.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```